# Multitasking on iPhone 5s while HDMI displays something else?

Tags: ios, iphone, hdmi, lightning, netflix

How can I keep HDMI playing movies while using other apps on my handset?

I initially thought that the adapter merely mirrored pixel-for-pixel, but during movie playback it is possible to reveal the double-tap application menu without affecting playback; selecting an app results on its being displayed on both displays and halting movie playback.

iOS 7.1.2, Apple Lightning-to-HDMI adapter, HDTV, Netflix app.

*I would prefer a factory setting or approved app to achieve this, but please do include jb solution if applicable.*

Answer (score 1):

Lock the phone, swipe to the left then back. Swipe up to bring up the calculator and then unlock the screen.
You should now be able to multitask.